# How to return a function as a query result in graphene?

Tags: django, web, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

I have a post model, and I want to know if the currently logged in user has liked the post or not:

Would something like this work or should I use a different request to know if the user has liked/not liked the post:

```
class PostNode(DjangoObjectType):
    id = graphene.ID(source='pk', required=True)
    liked = graphene.Boolean(source=Like.objects.filter(user=info.context.user,post=Post.objects.get(pk=id)))
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        interfaces = (graphene.relay.Node,)
```

(of course it doen't work)

The query:

```
query {
posts {
  edges {
    node {
      liked
      title
      text
    }
  }
}
```

}

The result:

```
{
   "data": {
       "posts": {
           "edges": [
               {
                   "node": {
                       "liked": false,
                       "title": "hi",
                       "text": "m"
                   }
               },
               {
                   "node": {
                      "liked": true,
                      "title": "blalblala",
                      "text": "blalalblala"
                    }
               }
           ]
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hard to know if that would work without having extra info about your schema :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [custom resolvers](https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/queries/#customising-fields) to achieve this behavior, like the following:

```py
class PostNode(DjangoObjectType):
    id = graphene.ID(required=True)
    liked = graphene.Boolean()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        interfaces = (graphene.relay.Node,)

    def resolve_liked(parent, info):
        # "parent" here is the Post model instance
        return Like.objects.exists(user=info.context.user, post=parent)
```